# Remove Comma from Case Statement

Tags: sql-server

I realise this is a common question, but I'm wanting to avoid having to repeat the CASE statements multiple times.

Can anyone see a way of how the "," can be excluded from the string if only a few Cases are true(1)?

```
SELECT CONCAT
(
    CASE WHEN Home = 1 THEN 'Own Home, ' END, 
    CASE WHEN Car = 1 THEN 'Car, ' END, 
    CASE WHEN Friend = 1 THEN 'Someone else''s home, ' END,
    CASE WHEN Toilet = 1 THEN 'Toilet, ' END,
    CASE WHEN Street = 1 THEN 'Street, park or beach, ' END,
    CASE WHEN Squat = 1 THEN 'Squat, ' END,
    CASE WHEN Other = 1 THEN 'Other' END
) 
as 'Question 6',
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT REVERSE(stuff(reverse(CONCAT
(
    CASE WHEN Home = 1 THEN 'Own Home, ' END, 
    CASE WHEN Car = 1 THEN 'Car, ' END, 
    CASE WHEN Friend = 1 THEN 'Someone else''s home, ' END,
    CASE WHEN Toilet = 1 THEN 'Toilet, ' END,
    CASE WHEN Street = 1 THEN 'Street, park or beach, ' END,
    CASE WHEN Squat = 1 THEN 'Squat, ' END,
    CASE WHEN Other = 1 THEN 'Other' END
)),1 ,1,''))
as 'Question 6',
from TABLE
```

OR this

```
SELECT STUFF(CONCAT
(
    CASE WHEN Home = 1 THEN ', Own Home' END, 
    CASE WHEN Car = 1 THEN ', Car' END, 
    CASE WHEN Friend = 1 THEN ', Someone else''s home' END,
    CASE WHEN Toilet = 1 THEN ', Toilet' END,
    CASE WHEN Street = 1 THEN ', Street, park or beach' END,
    CASE WHEN Squat = 1 THEN ', Squat' END,
    CASE WHEN Other = 1 THEN ', Other' END
),1,2,'') 
as 'Question 6',
from table
```

Comment: @James What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I tried with sample data and it works fine. Can you provide your sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the fastest, but just for fun.

```
WITH T3 AS 
(
    SELECT T1.PK, COALESCE(T2.Description, unpvt.Place) AS Description
    FROM table AS T1
    UNPIVOT
        (Flag FOR Place IN (Home, Car, Friend, Toilet, Street, Squat, Other)
    ) AS unpvt
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM (VALUES('Home', 'Own Home'), ('Friend', 'Someone else''s home'), ('Street', 'Street, park or beach')) AS T(Place, Description)
    ) AS T2 ON unpvt.Place = T2.Place
    WHERE Flag = 1
)
SELECT PK, (STUFF((
                SELECT ', ' + Description
                FROM T3 AS T4
                WHERE T4.PK = T3.PK
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')) AS Question6
FROM T3
GROUP BY PK
```

To preserve order in question, just add an order column to T2 above.

With SQL Server 2017, it's simpler.

```
SELECT T1.PK, STRING_AGG(COALESCE(T2.Description, unpvt.Place), ', ') AS Description
FROM table AS T1
UNPIVOT
    (Flag FOR Place IN (Home, Car, Friend, Toilet, Street, Squat, Other)
) AS unpvt
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('Home', 'Own Home'), ('Friend', 'Someone else''s home'), ('Street', 'Street, park or beach')) AS T(Place, Description)
) AS T2 ON unpvt.Place = T2.Place
WHERE Flag = 1
GROUP BY PK
```